# Testing with puppeteer an AWS amplify react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I would like to test  a react application with AWS amplify authentication ( using cognito).

The first step is log in to the app filling the input fileds (email and password) and submit the login form

await page.waitForSelector("#email");
await page.type("#email", "email@example.com", {delay: 500});

await page.waitForSelector("#pass");
await page.type("#pass", "secret", {delay: 500});

then the submit event

But with amplify it didn't works - the input elements are not finded

The form is the following

[form login amplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0bMd.png)

As you can see the html element form username is just input#username , but if I try to select sthe elemtns with plain JS , it doesnt work

[i cant find the input elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PslyH.png)

How could I set the value to the form fields and submit the form for puppeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the username and password input being in the shadow dom, that's why it's not able to find it. Check out https://github.com/Georgegriff/query-selector-shadow-dom , this tool will make your life easier.

Here is a made up example using the Amplify default SignIn modal:

```
const { Given, When, Then, setDefaultTimeout } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const {  QueryHandler, } = require("query-selector-shadow-dom/plugins/puppeteer");

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);


Given('I visit the myWebsitewebsite', async function () {
    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        devtools: false
    });
    this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
    await puppeteer.registerCustomQueryHandler('shadow', QueryHandler);
    await this.page.goto('https://example.mywebsite.com', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    });
});

When('enter my credentials', async function () {
    const userNameField = await this.page.waitForSelector("shadow/#username");
    const passWordField = await this.page.waitForSelector("shadow/#password");
    
    await userNameField.type("xxxxxxxxx");  
    await passWordField.type("xxxxxxxxxxx");
    await this.page.keyboard.press("Enter")
});

Then('I see my dashboard', async function () {
    await this.page.waitFor("#dashboard-card");
    await this.browser.close();
    
});
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a frustrating answer if I am wrong, but it seems as though you didn't use the correct id. Judging from this screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0bMd.png) it seems the id is actually `username.input` and in the second screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PslyH.png) you seem to think the id stops at `username`

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Hope this actually works